# Get all changes to calendar in Outlook Web Add-in

Tags: outlook, add-in, office-app

I'm developing an add-in for Outlook Web (Outlook365 and Outlook.com) which needs to retrieve all changes in the calendar.

I tried to use the Calendar REST API, but when calling `getCallbackTokenAsync` to get the access token, the token I get is scoped, and when I call the Calendar REST API, I get this error:

> {"error":{"code":"ErrorAccessDenied","message":"The api you are trying to access does not support item scoped OAuth."}}.

Does anyone have an idea about this or another way to get changed items?

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue with this , just about attachments. 
You need to set permissions of 'ReadWriteMailbox' in your manifest and then it's supposed to return 200 and not error..but right now there is a bug in outlook.

Read more here: [Can't add attachment to message in outlook add-in using Outlook rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42420073/cant-add-attachment-to-message-in-outlook-add-in-using-outlook-rest-api)

Good luck .

Comment: Thanks OriEng, a workaround is to use adal.js for authentification then call the Graph API.