# Issue with PATCH method of outlook mail REST API returning ErrorAccessDenied

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We have an outlook add-in for which we need to update the single-value-extended-property of a mail item using it's itemId.

**Documentation for updating the extension property**: [**Here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty-post-singlevalueextendedproperties?view=graph-rest-1.0#request-headers)

We got the following response for the HTTP call:

**Request Url:**

```
PATCH https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/messages('{mailItemId}')
```

**Response:**

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
        "message": "The api you are trying to access does not support item scoped OAuth."
    }
}
```

On tweaking further, we found that there maybe an issue with the auth token that we are using in the request headers. We are using the Outlook's `getCallbackTokenAsync` api to fetch the token, with `isRest` option set to true for REST token. On searching around in stack-overflow for relevant issues, I found these questions:

> 1. [Can't add attachment to message in outlook add-in using Outlook rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42420073/cant-add-attachment-to-message-in-outlook-add-in-using-outlook-rest-api)
> 2. [Access to Outlook RestAPI from an Outlook web Add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42222773/access-to-outlook-restapi-from-an-outlook-web-add-in/42233494)

These suggest that there maybe a bug in this api, due to which it returns an item scoped token instead of a mailbox scoped one. The payload of an item scoped token contains `Exchange.Callback.V1` as the value of the version and `Exchange.Callback.V2` for a mailbox scoped one.

We decoded our response token on https://jwt.io/ and found that the token returned was indeed an item scoped one, and hence we are blocked on pushing the updated value of extended-property to the mail item. It was also written that this issue may get resolved in the builds after 16.0.7902.1000. I am trying this on web-browser client for Outlook though, and not sure how the build version is relevant in my case.

Has anyone else faced such behavior recently, or is there any possible work-around for the issue?

************** **EDIT** ****************

I followed the suggestion in the comment, and am now able to execute the patch request from postman, but not from within the add-in. I get a 400 bad request error in the console. Below is a version of the response with the particular key name and url removed.

```
{ 
  "_body": { 
    "error":{ 
      "code":"RequestBodyRead", 
      "message":"An unexpected instance annotation name '{key name}' was found 
                 when reading from the JSON reader, In OData, Instance 
                 annotation name must start with @."
    } 
  }, 
  "status": 400, 
  "ok": false, 
  "statusText": "Bad Request", 
  "type": 2 
}
```

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: Please have a look at getCallbackTokenAsync API doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.5/office.context.mailbox#getcallbacktokenasyncoptions-callback . You need to specify ReadWriteMailbox permission in its manifest.

Comment: Ah right! This solved my issue. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at getCallbackTokenAsync API doc : learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/… . You need to specify ReadWriteMailbox permission in its manifest.